# ImageView not Displaying Uri

Tags: android, string, imageview, uri

I have an image view and if there is an album cover I want to display it with this method and if there isn't I want to display a default image.  But when I run this, it displays nothing. Here is the code:

```
 //Recieves it from a bundle
     String albumarturi = names.getString("artworkkeyword");
     String tempstring = albumarturi;
     Uri myUri = Uri.parse(albumarturi)


   if(tempstring == null){
            artworkimageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noartwork));
     }else{
        artworkimageview.setImageURI(myUri);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `albumarturi` is not a valid URI. It must be pointing to a valid resource.

Comment: It is coming from here                                             Uri sArtworkUri= Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, ALBUM_ID);
                
                album_url = uri.toString();